# Oracle source preview not working in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, oracle11g, oracle12c, sql-server-2016, ssis

I'm in the process of a SQL Server upgrade & migration from 2008-R2 to 2016.
I've migrated the databases and the SSIS packages with SQL Server Data Tools. I've got the Oracle clients Oracle 11g & 12 installed and configured as OracleHome. My TNSNAMES file has the correct servername and port. When I execute the package in Visual Studio 2015 it runs perfectly. The package reads from the Oracle Source and writes to my SQL DB. But when I want to preview the Oracle data in the OLE DB Source editor I get the error:

```
The system cannot find message text for message number 0x80040e51 in the message file for OraOLEDB. (OraOLEDB)
```

I've been doing a lot of reading and have tried a couple of suggestions, but I'm still getting the error. Does anyone recognize this problem? Can someone please point me in the right direction. Thanks!

SQL Server: 2016
Visual Studio : 2015
Oracle client/provider: 11g & 12
Oracle DB version: 11

Robert

Comment: I'm getting the same issue on 2 different systems. System 1: Windows 10 x64 1703, VS2015 Update 3, SSDT 17.2, Oracle Client 12.1.0.2. System 2: Windows Server 2012R2, SSDT 17.2 (VS 2015 integrated shell), Oracle Client 12.1.0.2. Packages run fine both in the designer as well as after deployment. Only issue is using the designer preview function. Other Oracle connectors (Attunity & ADO.NET both tested) work fine.

Comment: Just spent some more time testing on another system of mine. SSDT 17.2 (on VS 2015) shows the issue. However, on the same system I have also installed the original SQL Server 2012 BIDS (ie .VS2010), as well as SSDT-BI for VS2012. On both of those, all using the same oracle client install (12.1.0.2, 32-bit), the preview function in the OLE DB data source worked without issue. Definitely seems like this is an issue with VS 2015 rather than the Oracle client.